# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors when trying to run client:build

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I am building an app with Gluon-mobile in InteliJ on Windows and having problems when I add additional dependencies via Maven. On Windows, when I add a new dependency to my pom file and try to run client:build from a command line I start getting getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors.

In this case I am trying to use the obs-websocket-java module and added the dependency in my pom file. I have tried other ones too and see to have the same problem.

Error Examples

```
[Tue Mar 09 16:39:58 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] We will now compile your code for x86_64-microsoft-windows. This may take some time.
[Tue Mar 09 16:39:58 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:00 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] [org.jdf.teamdatacollect:20756]    classlist:   1,404.15 ms,  0.96 GB
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] [org.jdf.teamdatacollect:20756]        (cap):   4,533.88 ms,  0.95 GB
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] [org.jdf.teamdatacollect:20756]        setup:   5,221.72 ms,  0.95 GB
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] Error: Error parsing reflection configuration in file:/C:/Users/joshu/IdeaProjects/TeamDataCollect/target/classes/META-INF%5cnative-image%5creflect-config.json:
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] Could not register net.twasi.obsremotejava.OBSCommunicator: allDeclaredMethods for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session. To allow unresolvable reflection configuration, use option -H:+AllowIncompleteClasspath
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option ReflectionConfigurationResources.
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error parsing reflection configuration in file:/C:/Users/joshu/IdeaProjects/TeamDataCollect/target/classes/META-INF%5cnative-image%5creflect-config.json:
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] Could not register net.twasi.obsremotejava.OBSCommunicator: allDeclaredMethods for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session. To allow unresolvable reflection configuration, use option -H:+AllowIncompleteClasspath
[Tue Mar 09 16:40:06 GMT-08:00 2021][INFO] [SUB] Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option ReflectionConfigurationResources.
[
```

pom file

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>teamdatacollect</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>TeamDataCollect</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.10</attach.version>
        <client.plugin.version>0.1.38</client.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>org.jdf.TeamDataCollect</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
            <version>0.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.twasi</groupId>
            <artifactId>obs-websocket-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${client.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>org.jdf.views.CollectDataPresenter</list>
                        <list>org.jdf.views.SetupPresenter</list>
                        <list>org.jdf.views.StreamingPresenter</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>display</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I have tried running the client:runagent but that doesn't seem to help. What I found in looking through the error logs is that the classpath in the classpathJar.jar manifest file which is in `target\client\x86_64-windows\gvm\tmp` does not contain all the jars that the obs-websocket-java modules depends on. If I run the native-image command by hand substituting a custom classpathJar.jar I am able to make further progress but still haven.t found a magic recipe to make it build

I have also found that the jni-config.json and reflect-config.json that is generated by the client:runagent seem to be missing many of the entries that I get when I run the Graalvm agent to generate these by hand. I don't know if this is related.

Is there a step that I am missing? Any and all help appreciated.

Joshua

Comment: Just in case, `client:runagent` has to discover all possible scenarios where reflection is used, so while running it you have to go through all scenes, views, menus... Also, you can manually edit the generated config files or you can add missing classes to the `reflectionList`.

Comment: I've tried going through every path I can think of with the client:runagent and this simply doesn't generate any entries to the reflect-config.json file that I seem to need. 

I did find that if I change some of the maven .pom files for the dependencies to say compile instead of just runtime that I was able to make most of this work. Still failing with sqllite ...